# Method of Data analysis

Tags: regression, anova, model, manova

For my research I am comparing actual purchases (in amounts of products bought) in different conditions. I'm examining whether applying a certain promotional intervention improves the amount of products bought. By accessing scanner data from supermarkets we can access the amounts of products bought in each condition.

So I have 4 conditions:

Normal shaped products + intervention

Normal shaped products + no intervention

Misshaped products + intervention

Misshaped products + no intervention

Where I'm stuck is when deciding on how to do the data analysis

• What should be the proposed method of data analysis (e.g ANOVA, regression, Chi-square, etc.)

Comment: This sounds like a two-way ANOVA. (ANOVA is a type of regression, by the way.)

Comment: This sounds as if there is only one amount (integer number) for each combination, true? In that case I'd say it calls for log-linear analysis. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-linear_analysis

Comment: Is there ex-ante reason to believe the errors are going to be Gaussian? Further, isn't this count data?

Comment: Yes it is count data. Scanner data from supermarkets will be taken from each intervention. So in the end you end up with 4 counts: 
1 - The amount of products bought of normal shape with intervention
2- The amount of products bought of normal shape withoit intervention
3- The amount of products bought of misshape with intervention
4- The amount of products bought of  misshape without intervention

And I am interested in measuring whether or not the intervention increased the amounts bought of misshapen products

Answer (score 0):

I think you essentially have 2 x 2 contigency table of counts. If you'd like to keep your analysis simple there are several measures of association you could use listed on the wiki page here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contingency_table#Measures_of_association

For more control you could also consider a log-linear model under Poisson, negative Binomial, or other assumptions. Have a look here:

https://data.princeton.edu/wws509/notes/c5.pdf

Comment: I can keep it quite simple. 
It is not required to do the actual analysis.
I just have to justify which one is neccesary to use in my research and why this is the case (in like 3/4 sentences)

Comment: Perhaps then have a look at the “odds ratio” article on Wikipedia and see if it does it for you.